# How to manually submit file in jQuery Blueimp fileupload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have already initialize the fileupload like this :

```
$('#my_fileupload_id').fileupload({
    blah blah blah
});
```

Now some part in code I want to submit that initialized fileupload like this :

```
$('#my_fileupload_id').fileupload().submit();
```

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was maddening to find the answer in the documentation but...

[From the Docs](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin#how-to-start-uploads-with-a-button-click)

What I used:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('#BUTTON_ID').click(function () {
                data.submit();
            });
    },
});
```